# Can't upload sound files in visualstudios server

Tags: asp.net, upload

Whenever I try to upload a sound file IO get the error "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.". The sound file is 5.58mb, an .OGG. My server is visual studios 9 (2008). The form uses enctype="multipart/form-data". I have a feeling it may be a filesize limit but I dont know where to change the file length allowed.

How do I fix a "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." problem in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the web.config:

```
  <system.web>
       <httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
        <sessionState timeout="60" />
  </system.web>
```

I've found lot more things you can put in httpruntime at [wrox](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/ASP-NET-2-0-FileUpload-Server-Control-Page-2.id-292159.html) site:

```
     <httpRuntime
     executionTimeout="110" 
     maxRequestLength="4096" 
     requestLengthDiskThreshold="80" 
     useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" 
     minFreeThreads="8" 
     minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" 
     appRequestQueueLimit="5000" 
     enableKernelOutputCache="true" 
     enableVersionHeader="true" 
     requireRootedSaveAsPath="true" 
     enable="true" 
     shutdownTimeout="90" 
     delayNotificationTimeout="5" 
     waitChangeNotification="0" 
     maxWaitChangeNotification="0" 
     enableHeaderChecking="true" 
     sendCacheControlHeader="true" 
     apartmentThreading="false" />
```