# File Upload doesn't hit controller method if filename contains parentheses VS2010 ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, upload, filenames, parentheses

In a Create view which properly starts with a...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Song", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

and among a few other fields has a...

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input type='file' name="SongFileUpload" id="SongFileUpload" onchange="readURL(this);" />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SongData)
</div>
```

ending with a

```
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
```

if I browse for and select a filename which contains a beginning and ending parentheses within the name... when I click on the "Create" button to submit it... when just running of the localhost server VS2010 provides... it just bops right over to the IE (v10) error of....

```
>This page can't be displayed
>
>•Make sure the web address http://localhost:63129 is correct.  
>•Look for the page with your search engine.  
>•Refresh the page in a few minutes.
```

At first I thought it might be because the filename began with an "@" symbol. but that's not it as I can select another filename that is similarly as long but does not contain the parentheses and it jumps into the

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Create( )
```

Like it should and everything works as it should.

What the heck as going on here?

Below is the JavaScript for the "readURL( )" function.

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#SongMimeType').attr('value', input.files[0].type);
            $('#SongData').InnerHtml = (e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

My guess is the JavaScript function is what might be blowing-up??
How would I fix it to handle this filenames with parentheses??

Comment: Have you tried to url encode the filename?

Comment: "url encode the filename" exactly where? In the JavaScript function?  Since that field is an `<input type="file"`control. When it is invoke it just pops up your typical File-> Open dialog box.  What other events are there similar to that "onchange" event that I have to work with?

Comment: To be clear... when I select the offending filename... when I click on submit it never goes back to (stops at) my debug points I set both in VS2010... and within the F12 Debugging available in IE. It goes directly to stating that error of `This page can't be displayed`

Comment: I reconstructed as much of your project as I could given the information in your post and I am wondering if it has to do with the file content versus the filename. Can you try removing the parentheses from the filename of the file in question and try again and see if it still errors?

Comment: it's not the content. It's the illegal chars in the filename. on w3school little "try It" sandbox I create a similar `<input>` where type is "file" field and it returned an error msg explaining that it contained illegal chars.  So today I'm figuring out how and where to intercept the filepath name and pass it thru url encoding as you suggested.

Comment: Pssh... it's not the characters. I think it's filesize. I just noticed that this one file is the only one in that folder that greater than 5000 K in size. I noticed it just now because I was testing renaming other files which I could browse to and upload successfully into a naming scheme matching this one file that's giving me grief... and it accepted it for upload even with a similar naming style. I was debugging trying to utilize encodeURI( ) to help with the imagined filename problem.

Comment: Grrr... this was the problem.. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067222/cant-upload-sound-files-in-visualstudios-server

Comment: Thank you for renaming the file when I asked :P